# S3 VPC Interface Endpoint Not Being Used

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-vpc

I have a lambda in us-east-2 deployed in a private subnet that needs to pull data from an S3 bucket in us-east-1. In order to avoid NAT gateway costs, I've setup a VPC Interface endpoint, but traffic is still being routed via the NAT. How can I ensure that traffic is routed through the VPC Interface endpoint instead of the NAT? My understanding is that because `private_dns_enabled`, it should automatically resolve cross-region S3 requests to the endpoint instead of the NAT.

Below is the terraform I used to create the VPC endpoint.

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "s3_global" {
  vpc_id       = aws_vpc.main.id
  vpc_endpoint_type = "Interface"
  service_name = "com.amazonaws.s3-global.accesspoint"
  subnet_ids = aws_subnet.private.*.id
  private_dns_enabled = true
}
```

Below is my S3 client setup:

```py
client_config = botocore.config.Config(
    max_pool_connections=settings.threads,
    connect_timeout=5,
    read_timeout=10,
    s3={"us_east_1_regional_endpoint": "regional"},
)
s3_client = boto3.client(
    "s3",
    aws_access_key_id=settings.aws_access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key=settings.aws_secret_access_key
    region_name="us-east-1",
    config=client_config,
)
```

Comment: It's possible you're using the incorrect S3 Endpoint Service URL. Try com.amazonaws.${REGION}.s3 | https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints-s3.html

Comment: You are creating a multi-region S3 access point. The code in your question would try to access a `us-east-1` access point, not the multi-region access point. You would need to follow this guide to access S3 through the multi-region endpoint: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/privatelink-interface-endpoints.html#private-dns If instead you created a single-region endpoint for `s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`, your code would work automatically.

Comment: @MarkB not sure if I'm missing something, but I can't create a us-east-1 access point in us-east-2. The only options I have are:
com.amazonaws.s3-global.accesspoint
com.amazonaws.us-east-2.s3
com.amazonaws.us-east-2.s3-outposts

Comment: I missed that it is deployed in us-east-2. That means your only option is to follow that user guide I linked to get your code to use the global endpoint. You might want to update your question to show the code you tried to for that already.